# Binary to decimal conversion and vice-versa

Tags: java, object-oriented, number-systems

I need to write a code for conversion between the decimal numbers and binary numbers. I have tried the problem and what I have is 3 classes and 1 enum type

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * The {@code Immutable} class {@code BinaryNumber} wraps a string
 * representation of a binary (base 2) number.The class uses a
 * string of ASCII digits {@code '0'} and {@code '1'} to represent
 * a binary number.
 *
 * <p>In addition,this class provides a several methods like for
 * converting a binary(base 2) to a signed {@code int}, swapping
 * bits position in a binary number, finding the {@code 1}s and {@code two}s
 * complement of a binary number and several other useful methods for doing
 * a binary calculation.
 *
 * The minimum and maximum length of binary sequence that can be represented by
 * object of this class is {@code 0} and {@code Integer.MAX_VALUE} respectively.
 *
 * @author Praveen Kumar
 */
public class BinaryNumber implements Iterable<Character> {
    // wrapped binary string
    private final String binaryString;
    // length of the binary number represented by a binary string
    private final int length;

    /**
     * Constructs a newly allocated {@code BinaryNumber} object that represents
     * a specified string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2).
     *
     * @param binaryString string of ASCII digits in binary(base 2)
                           i.e.,{@code '0'} and {@code '1'}.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the argument cannot represent a
                                        binary(base 2) number.
     */
    public BinaryNumber(String binaryString) {
        if (binaryString.matches("[01]+")) {
            this.binaryString = binaryString;
            length = binaryString.length();
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(binaryString+": Invalid Entries for Binary representation");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the length of this {@code BinaryNumber}.the length will be equal
     * to the total number of ASCII character in a binary string represented by
     * this {@code BinaryNumber} object.
     *
     * @return int the number of the ASCII characters({@code '0'} and {@code '1'})
                   in this object.
     */
    public int length() {
        return length;
    }

    /**
     * returns a new {@code BinaryNumber} equivalent to this {@code BinaryNumber}
     * object but having a length equals to the argument(size).
     * the new object would be padded with leading {@code 0}s or {@code 1}s accordingly the
     * unsigned decimal equivalent(with {@code 2}s complement) of this object is positive or
     * negative.
     * this method will not allow for the Narrowing conversion({@code size < length()}) and
     * throws exception in such case.
     *
     * @param size the needed size of a binary sequence represented by this object.
     * @return BinaryNumber having a length equals to the argument and is equivalent
                            to this object.
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the specified size is less than the size
                                         of the binary sequence represented by this
                                         object.
     */
    public BinaryNumber toSize(int size) {
        if  (size < length()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(size+": Narrowing Conversion is not allowed.");
        }
        StringBuilder mutableBinString = new StringBuilder(binaryString);
        mutableBinString.reverse();
        while (mutableBinString.length() != size) {
            if(isNegative()) {
                mutableBinString.append('1');
            }
            else {
                mutableBinString.append('0');
            }
        }
        mutableBinString.reverse();
        BinaryNumber binaryNum = new BinaryNumber(mutableBinString.toString());
        if (isNegative()) {
        return binaryNum.swapBitsPosn(0, size - length);
        }
        return binaryNum;
    }

    /**
     * returns a {@code String} object representing a binary sequence in this object.
     *
     *@return String representation of binary sequence(base 2) represented by this object.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return binaryString;
    }

    /**
     * returns a new {@code BinaryNumber} having a binary sequence equivalent to performing a
     * {@code 1}s complement on the binary sequence represented by this object.
     *
     * @return BinaryNumber the {@code 1}s complement of the char sequence represented by
                            this object.
     */
    public BinaryNumber onesComplement() {
        StringBuilder mutableBinString = new StringBuilder(binaryString);
        for (int i = 0; i < mutableBinString.length(); i++) {
            char flippedBit = (mutableBinString.charAt(i) == '0' ? '1' : '0');
            mutableBinString.setCharAt(i, flippedBit);
        }
        return new BinaryNumber(mutableBinString.toString());
    }

    private class BinaryIterator implements Iterator<Character> {
        char[] bits = binaryString.toCharArray();

        int index = 0;

        /*
         * Tests if the iteration has more bit character left while traversing
         * in the char sequence represented by this object.
         *
         * @return {@code true} if the binary sequence represented by this object
                               has one or more bit character left for iteration;
                               {@code false} otherwise.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < bits.length;
        }

        /*
         * returns the next bit {@code Character} in the binary sequence represented
         * by this object while iteration.
         *
         * @return Character the next bit character in the binary sequence represented
                             by this object.
         * @throws NoSuchElementException if the binary sequence reprsented by this
                                          object doesnot have next bit {@code Character}.
         */
        @Override
        public Character next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            else {
                return bits[index++];
            }
        }

        /* this method will throws an exception every time when it is invoked because this
         * operation is not supported on the binary sequence represented by this object.
         *
         * @throws UnsupportedOperationException every time when it is invoked.
         */
        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Removal: Invalid Operation");
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns a iterator of {@code Character} over a binary sequence represented by this object.
     *
     * @return {@code Iterator<Character>} the iterator providing the iteration on bit character
                                           of the binary sequence represented by this object.
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator<Character> iterator() {
        return new BinaryIterator();
    }

    /**
     * Tests if the signed decimal(with {@code 2}s complement) equivalent of the binary sequence
     * represented by this object is negative.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if the signed decimal equivalent of the binary sequence represented by
                            this object is negative;{@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isNegative() {
        char signBit = binaryString.charAt(0);
        return signBit == '1' ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * returns a new {@code BinaryNumber} having a binary sequence equivalent to the binary sequence
     * of this object but with the bits position of the {@code i}th and the {@code j}th index of the
     * binary sequence(in this object) interchanged(in the new object).
     *
     * @return BinaryNumber with binary sequence having the {@code i}th and the {@code j}th index
                            interchanged in the binary sequence represented by this object.
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if either argument {@code i} or {@code j} is negative or
     *                                   greater than the length of the binary sequence represented
                                         by this object.
     */
    public BinaryNumber swapBitsPosn(int i, int j) {
        boolean swapPossibility = (i >= 0) && (j >=0) && (i < length) && (j < length);
        if (!swapPossibility) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Illegal Index");
        }
        StringBuilder mutableBinString = new StringBuilder(this.binaryString);
        char ithBit = mutableBinString.charAt(i);
        mutableBinString.setCharAt(i, mutableBinString.charAt(j));
        mutableBinString.setCharAt(j, ithBit);
        return new BinaryNumber(mutableBinString.toString());
    }

    /**
     * returns a {@code int} equivalent of a binary sequence represented by
     * this object.this invocation is only allowed on the {@code BinaryNumber}
     * object having a length less than or equal to {@code Integer.SIZE}
     * ;otherwise the invocation will throw an exception.
     *
     * @return signed integer(with {@code 2}s complement) equivalent of the
     * binary sequence represented by this object.
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the length of the binary sequence
                                             represented by this object is greater
                                             than the {@code Integer.SIZE}.
     */
    public int toDecimalInt() {
        if (length() > Integer.SIZE) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Integer can only hold "+Integer.SIZE+" bits.");
        }
        int decInt = 0;
        BinaryNumber binaryNum = this;
        boolean Negative = isNegative();
        if (Negative) {
            binaryNum = twosComplement();
        }
        Iterator<Character> iterator = binaryNum.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
            char next = iterator.next();
            if (next == '1') {
                decInt = decInt + twoRaisedToPow((binaryNum.length() - i - 1));
            }
        }
        return Negative ? -decInt : decInt;
    }

    private static int twoRaisedToPow(int i) {
        assert (i > 0 && i < 32) : "invalid shift";
        return 1 << i;
    }

    /**
     * returns the {@code 2}s complement representation of the binary
     * sequence represented by this object.
     *
     * @return BinaryNumber having the binary sequence equivalent to the
                            {@code 2}s complement of the binary sequence
                            represented by this object.
     */
    public BinaryNumber twosComplement() {
        BinaryNumber binNum = onesComplement();
        StringBuilder mutableBinString = new StringBuilder(binNum.binaryString);
        mutableBinString.reverse();
        for (int i = 0; i < binNum.length(); i++) {
            if (mutableBinString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                mutableBinString.setCharAt(i, '0');
                continue;
            }
            mutableBinString.setCharAt(i, '1');
            break;
        }
        mutableBinString.reverse();
        return new BinaryNumber(mutableBinString.toString());
    }
}
```

DecimalNumber.java

```
/**
 * The {@code DecimalNumber} class wraps a primitive data type {@code int}.
 * The object of type {@code DecimalNumber} will be helpful when doing a
 * conversion of a type {@code int} to {@code BinaryNumber}.
 *
 * @author Praveen Kumar
 */
public class DecimalNumber {
    // wrapped int
    private final int value;

    /**
     * Constructs a newly allocated {@code DecimalNumber} object that represents
     * the specified {@code int} value.
     *
     * @param integer The primitive {@code int} value represented by {@code this}
     * object.
     */
    public DecimalNumber(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a {@code BinaryNumber}(base 2)
     * representation of unsigned {@code int} equivalent to {@code int}
     * represented by {@code this} object.
     * The unsigned {@code int} equivalent is the {@code int} represented by
     * this object plus 2<sup>32</sup> if the represented {@code int} is negative;
     * otherwise it is equal to the represented {@code int} of {@code this} object.
     * for clearity here is the example: let the represented {@code int = -8} than the
     * equivalent unsigned {@code int} will be 2<sup>32</sup> {@code + (-8)}.
     *
     * <p>The {@code BinaryNumber} returned by this method will contains the leading
     * {@code 0}s if the size of the binary string equivalent to the {@code int}
     * represented by {@code this} object is less than 32.
     * and in that case The number of leading {@code 0}s will be 32 minus the minimum number
     * of bits required to convert {@code int} to a binary number.
     *
     * @return BinaryNumber the binary equivalent of the {@code int} represented by
               {@code this} object.
     */
    public BinaryNumber toBinaryNumber() {
        int i = Math.abs(value);
        StringBuilder mutableBinString = new StringBuilder();
        while (i != 0) {
            mutableBinString.append(isEven(i) ? '0' : '1');
            i >>>= 1;
        }
        mutableBinString.append('0');
        mutableBinString.reverse();
        BinaryNumber binaryNum;
        if (value < 0) {
            binaryNum = new BinaryNumber(mutableBinString.toString()).twosComplement();
            return binaryNum.toSize(Integer.SIZE);
        }
        binaryNum = new BinaryNumber(mutableBinString.toString());
        return binaryNum.toSize(Integer.SIZE);
    }

    /**
     * Tests if the specified argument is a Even Number.
     *
     *@param i the {@code int} to be tested.
     *@returns {@code true} if the arugument is a Even Number;{@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isEven(int i) {
        return (i & 1) == 0;
    }
}
```

enum ConversionType.java for representing conversions binary to decimal and decimal to binary.

```
/**
 * Enum for conversion from one base to another like from decimal to binary,
 * binary to decimal etc.Every constant represent a specific conversion type
 * like for Example: the {@link BinaryNumber#DECIMAL_TO_BINARY DECIMAL_TO_BINARY}
 * represent a conversion from base 10 to base 2.
 *
 * @author Praveen Kumar
 */
public enum ConversionType {
    /**
     * Represents a conversion type from base 10 to base 2.
     */
    DECIMAL_TO_BINARY {
        @Override
        public String convert(String arg) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            try {
                int integer = Integer.parseInt(arg);
                DecimalNumber decimalNum = new DecimalNumber(integer);
                return decimalNum.toBinaryNumber().toString();
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException cause) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(cause);
            }
        }
    },
    /**
     * Represents a conversion type from base 2 to base 10.
     */
    BINARY_TO_DECIMAL {
        @Override
        public String convert(String arg) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            try {
                BinaryNumber binaryNum = new BinaryNumber(arg);
                int value = binaryNum.toDecimalInt();
                return "" + value;
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException cause) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(cause);
            }
            catch(UnsupportedOperationException cause) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(cause);
            }

        }
    };

    /**
     * Converts the argument to a string representing the another base and is equivalent
     * to the base represented by the argument.the conversion will take place accordingly
     * with the Enum constant {@code ConversionType}.
     *
     * @param arg the string representation of the base to be converted to another base.
     * @return the string representation of a converted base.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the argument string is not parsable to the
                                        base to be converted.
     */
    public abstract String convert(String arg) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

finally the functional class whose object is providing the functions of doing a conversion.

```
public class Convertor {
    private final ConversionType conversionType;

    public Convertor(ConversionType conversionType) {
     this.conversionType = conversionType;
    }

    public String convert(String arg) {
     return conversionType.convert(arg);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
     Convertor con = new Convertor(ConversionType.DECIMAL_TO_BINARY);
     // conversion code goes here...
    }
}
```

With decimal number I have initially made a convention to deal with Java int for a start.
Now I just want to know if I can make this code better. I want to stick to OO design as much as I can.

Comment: Question: Why isn't `binaryNumber` a wrapped `int` just like `decimalNumber`?  Seems like everything your functions do to the binary number could be done more easily to an `int` than to a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff I noticed, from start to end:

---

> ```
> private final String binaryString;
> ```

This limits you in what you can do with your wrapped number effectively. I strongly suggest considering to instead use a `char[]`.

---

throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` in a constructor is basically bad form, because instead of resulting in an `IllegalArgumentException`, the JLS mandates that the Exception be wrapped into an `ExceptionInInitializerError` which makes all this stuff moot. (For details [see JLS 12 §4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2))
Long story short: I'm pretty sure you want a factory method that performs the argument validation for you like:

```
public static BinaryNumber fromString(String binaryString) {
    if (!binaryString.matches("[01]+")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
    }
    return new BinaryNumber(binaryString);
}
```

Note that this requires you to make the constructor private to avoid messes with incorrect initialization.

---

Why is `length` cached in the code? It's always correct to use `binaryString.length()` instead, isn't it?

---

`toSize` could be significantly easier as:

```
if (size < binaryString.length()) {
    throw new ...
}
final char padChar = isNegative() ? '1' : '0';
final int padCount = binaryString.length() - size;
final StringBuilder mutableContainer = new StringBuilder(binaryString);
for (int i = 0; i < padCount; i++) {
    mutableContainer.insert(0, padChar);
}
BinaryNumber binaryNum = new BinaryNum(mutableContainer.toString());
...
```

note that this could be quite a bit cleaner if you used a `char[]`. If you did that, you could have done something like this:

```
char[] newRepresentation = new char[size];
Arrays.fill(newRepresentation, isNegative() ? '1' : '0');
System.arraycopy(representation, 0, newRepresentation, size - representation.length, representation.length);
// do that strange swapBitsPosn thing here
```

This is conceptually much simpler (and quite probably faster) than putting it into a StringBuffer, reversing twice and in the middle appending chars in a loop (which are determined by an if-statement depending on a method call ...)

---

The one's complement could be easier if you worked on a `char[]`, too... how is an exercise left to the reader.

---

> ```
> return signBit == '1' ? true : false;
> ```

should be `return signBit == '1';`, which is the same, but shorter and quicker...

---

Did I also mention that `swapBitsPosn` would also be simpler with a `char[]`???  Well I'm feeling like a broken record now ...

---

`toDecimalInt` can be significantly simplified when you start using binary arithmetics and binary operators ...

```
int decInt = 0;
// pad the representation to integer size to simplify shifting
char[] representation = toSize(Integer.SIZE).representation;
for (int i = 0; i < representation.length; i++) {
    if (representation[i] == '1') {
        decInt |= 1;
    }
    decInt << 1;
}
return decInt;
```

Note that this completely eliminates the need for a `twoRaisedToPow`...

---

You can get rid of `reverse` in `twosComplement` when you make the for-loop iterate from the back like so:

```
for (int i = binNum.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
// repeat code here
}
```

I'll just ignore the rest of the code for now, but I think you get the gist ...

Comment: Throwing exceptions in a constructor will not lead to an ExceptionInInitializerError, only exceptions thrown in static initializers/initializers of static variables are wrapped.

Comment: @Nevay aahh you're right ... I must've mixed up 12.4 and 12.5 from the JLS ("Initialization" and "Creation of new Class Instances") a bit...